# C# Or operator Issue

Tags: c#, if-statement, operator-keyword

I am pretty sure someone of you can help me with this issue.
I do not find and do not understand the solution.

```
if (hero.IsAlive || creature.IsAlive == false)
        {
            if (hero.IsAlive == true)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                EnemyHitInterface();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
                hero.Exp += 150;
                baseSetting.YouWin();
                hero.UpdateLvL();
                hero.CharacterInterface(hero);
                hero.PrintStatsHero();
                Console.ReadKey();
                CheckForItem();
                hero.PrintStatsHero();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (creature.IsAlive == true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                CenterText("You are dead. See you next time...", 15);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Simple if Operation with asks in my opinion, as soon as the hero dies or the creature it will get triggered.
If the creature dies, everything is fine, but if the hero dies it wont be triggered.
What is the think i do not understand?

For me it is like:

When Hero or Creature dies, go in
If hero is alive do this
if creature is alive do this

But like I said, as for the creature it wont work

Comment: I think your confusion is: `if (hero.IsAlive || creature.IsAlive == false)` is parsed as `if ((hero.IsAlive) || (creature.IsAlive == false))`, i.e. the same as `if (hero.IsAlive || !creature.IsAlive)`, or the same as `if ((hero.IsAlive == true) || (creature.IsAlive == false))`. I think you wanted to write `if (!hero.IsAlive || !creature.IsAlive)`

Comment: That outer if means the else if won't be hit. It's not Schrodinger's Creature, it can't be dead and alive at the same time.

Comment: Side Note: Using `if (booleanFlag == true)` is generally poor practice. You *already* have a boolean value to check (the flag itself), there's no need for the comparison, just do `if (booleanFlag)`. Similarly, `if (booleanFlag == false)` is more idiomatically written as `if (!booleanFlag)`. And following that convention would have prevented the error in your first `if` statement, which (if I understand what you wanted) should be `if (!hero.IsAlive || !creature.IsAlive)`.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you read this line

```
if (hero.IsAlive || creature.IsAlive == false)
```

in your head as "If hero or creature are dead". What it actually says is "If hero is alive or creature is dead". And if you follow through the rest of your logic, you'll see why you never hit the `else if (creature.IsAlive == true)` part.

What you (I think) wanted in the first if statement was

```
if (hero.IsAlive == false || creature.IsAlive == false) // if either are dead
```

or, more usually written

```
if (!hero.IsAlive || !creature.IsAlive) // if either are dead
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks a simple logic mistake:

```
if (hero.IsAlive || creature.IsAlive == false)
```

Is the same as:

```
if ((hero.IsAlive == true) || (creature.IsAlive == false))
```

But then, inside the if block you're checking:

```
if (hero.IsAlive == true)
        {
         ...
        }
        else if (creature.IsAlive == true)
        {
         ...
        }
    }
```

Which, if you combine them is:

```
if ((hero.isAlive == true && hero.IsAlive == true) || (creature.IsAlive == false && hero.IsAlive == true))
{
    ...
}
else if ((hero.IsAlive == true && creature.IsAlive == true) || (creature.IsAlive == false && creature.IsAlive == true))
{
    ...
}
```

But `(creature.IsAlive == false && creature.IsAlive == true)` is always false, and `(hero.isAlive == true && hero.IsAlive == true)` is always true.

So, to rejig your logic:

```
if (hero.IsAlive != creature.IsAlive ) //Either the hero or creature is dead
{
    if (hero.IsAlive)
    {
        //Hero is alive, creature is dead
    }
    else 
    {
       //Creature is alive, hero is dead.
    }
}
else if (hero.IsAlive)
{
    //Hero and creature are both alive
}
else 
{
    //Hero and creature are both dead
}
```

Should capture the behaviour you want.

Comment: You changed the logic at the end. If they're both dead it does not enter the outermost `if`